# trouble storing higher timeframe swing points on lower timeframe chart.?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

here is a sample of the code im using, it is supposed to find higher timeframe swing points and mark them on the lower timeframe chart selected. the trouble im having is it works but its intermittent. for example the gold chart (xauusd) if i select 12hr as my high timeframe and then have the hourly chart as my displayed chart. it will not show all the higher timeframe swings. the frustrating part is if i do a bar replay it shows all the swings correctly but the moment it gets to the current bar some of the swing points will disappear.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © samowen92

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)


HTF_user = input.timeframe(    defval  = "12 hour", 
                               title   = "Select high time-frame interval: ", 
                               options = ["Monthly", "Weekly", "Daily", "12 hour", "4 hour", "1 hour", "15 minute"], 
                               group   = "Chart setting's: ")     // High time-frame user selection (def = 12hr)


draw_HTF_market_swings = input.string(   defval  = "Off", 
                                         title   = "Draw HTF market swing: ", 
                                         options = ["Both","High","Low","Off"], 
                                         inline  = "Market Swings", 
                                         group   = "Market Swings")                      //  Display swing high's on chart


swing_amount = input.int(                defval  = 30, 
                                         title   = "Display how many swings?", 
                                         confirm = true, 
                                         group   = "Market Swings")  


settings_stored_swings = input.int(      defval  = 20, 
                                         title   = "How many swing point's should the bot store.", 
                                         minval  = 20, 
                                         maxval  = 100, 
                                         tooltip = "Set's the amount of swing high's and lows the bot will store in an array. (Does not change displayed amount)", 
                                         group   = "Debug settings")


float       []  iohlc                   = array.new_float()
var float   []  HTF_candle_request      = array.new_float()
var label   []  HTF_swing_high_label    = array.new_label()
var label   []  HTF_swing_low_label     = array.new_label() 
var             nested_HTF_candle       = matrix.new<float>()
var             nested_HTF_swing_high   = matrix.new<float>()
var             nested_HTF_swing_low    = matrix.new<float>()

 



var HTF = switch HTF_user
    "Monthly"   =>  "4W"
    "Weekly"    =>  "1W"
    "Daily"     =>  "1D"
    "12 hour"   =>  "720"
    "4 hour"    =>  "240"
    "1 hour"    =>  "60"
    "15 minute" =>  "15"


// Get high time-frame Index, Open, High, Low, Close. Without repainting
marketHighTF = barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0
marketCurrTF = barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1

// Count how many bars printed on the previous high time-frame session
new_session = ta.change(time(HTF))
var bars_this_session = 0
var bars_last_session = 0
if not new_session
    bars_this_session := bars_this_session + 1
else
    bars_last_session := bars_this_session + 1
    bars_this_session := 0

// Calculates bars per high time-frame bar
int bars_total_HTF = bars_this_session + bars_last_session

plotchar(bars_last_session, "Bars per HTF", "", color = color.white)
plotchar(bars_this_session, "Intrabar count", "", color = color.white)
plotchar(bars_total_HTF, "Total bars", "", color = color.white)


array.clear(HTF_candle_request)


//INDEX//
array.push(HTF_candle_request, request.security(syminfo.tickerid, str.tostring(HTF) , bar_index[marketHighTF], barmerge.gaps_on)[marketCurrTF])                   // High time-frame bar index

//OPEN//
array.push(HTF_candle_request, request.security(syminfo.tickerid, str.tostring(HTF) , open[marketHighTF], barmerge.gaps_on)[marketCurrTF])                        // High time-frame open



//HIGH//
array.push(HTF_candle_request, request.security(syminfo.tickerid, str.tostring(HTF) , high[marketHighTF], barmerge.gaps_on)[marketCurrTF])                        // High time-frame high



//LOW//
array.push(HTF_candle_request, request.security(syminfo.tickerid, str.tostring(HTF) , low[marketHighTF], barmerge.gaps_on)[marketCurrTF])                         // High time-frame low



//CLOSE//
array.push(HTF_candle_request, request.security(syminfo.tickerid, str.tostring(HTF), close[marketHighTF], barmerge.gaps_on)[marketCurrTF])                       // High time-frame high //



// Checks to see if this is the first high time-frame candle
if(matrix.rows(nested_HTF_candle) < 1)                   
    matrix.add_row(nested_HTF_candle, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_candle), HTF_candle_request) 

if(na(array.get(HTF_candle_request,0)) == false) 
    matrix.add_row(nested_HTF_candle, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_candle), HTF_candle_request)   


while matrix.rows(nested_HTF_candle) > 500                                                                                                          // Removes last high time frame candle from the nested array if it is larger then specified. (50) 
    matrix.remove_row(nested_HTF_candle, 0) 


is_swing_high_HTF() =>
    if(matrix.rows(nested_HTF_candle) >= 3 )

        while(matrix.rows(nested_HTF_swing_high) > settings_stored_swings)
            matrix.remove_row(nested_HTF_swing_high, 0)
        
        count = 0

        high0 = matrix.get(nested_HTF_candle, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_candle)-1, 2)
        high1 = matrix.get(nested_HTF_candle, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_candle)-2, 2)
        high2 = matrix.get(nested_HTF_candle, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_candle)-3, 2)
        

        if(high1 > high0 and high1 > high2 and bars_this_session == 0)


            for i = bars_total_HTF + bars_last_session to 0
                if(high[i] == high1)
                    
                    array.clear(iohlc)
                    array.push(iohlc, bar_index[i])                    // I O H L C
                    array.push(iohlc, open[i])
                    array.push(iohlc, high[i])
                    array.push(iohlc, low[i])
                    array.push(iohlc, close[i])
                    matrix.add_row(nested_HTF_swing_high, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_swing_high), iohlc)
                    count := count+1
                    break 

            
        if(count > 0)
            true
    else
        false




is_swing_low_HTF() =>
    if(matrix.rows(nested_HTF_candle) >= 3)

        while(matrix.rows(nested_HTF_swing_low) > settings_stored_swings)
            matrix.remove_row(nested_HTF_swing_low, 0)

        count = 0

        low0 = matrix.get(nested_HTF_candle, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_candle)-1, 3)
        low1 = matrix.get(nested_HTF_candle, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_candle)-2, 3)
        low2 = matrix.get(nested_HTF_candle, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_candle)-3, 3)
       

        if(low1 < low0 and low1 < low2 and bars_this_session == 0)
        
 
            for i = bars_total_HTF + bars_last_session to 0
                if(low[i] == low1)
            
                    array.clear(iohlc)
                    array.push(iohlc, bar_index[i])                    // I O H L C
                    array.push(iohlc, open[i])
                    array.push(iohlc, high[i])
                    array.push(iohlc, low[i])
                    array.push(iohlc, close[i])
                    matrix.add_row(nested_HTF_swing_low, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_swing_low), iohlc)
                    count := count+1
                    break
        if(count > 0)
            true
    else
        false







swing_highHTF = is_swing_high_HTF()

if(swing_highHTF)
    if(draw_HTF_market_swings == "High" or draw_HTF_market_swings == "Both")

        while(array.size(HTF_swing_high_label) >= swing_amount)
            label.delete(array.shift(HTF_swing_high_label))
       
        array.push(HTF_swing_high_label, label.new(
                         int(matrix.get(nested_HTF_swing_high, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_swing_high)-1, 0)), 
                         matrix.get(nested_HTF_swing_high, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_swing_high)-1, 2), 
                         yloc = yloc.abovebar, 
                         text = "HTF swing high" + "\n" + str.tostring(matrix.get(nested_HTF_swing_high, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_swing_high)-1, 2)), 
                         color = color.red, 
                         size = size.tiny, 
                         style = label.style_label_down))   


                                                                                                     






swing_lowHTF = is_swing_low_HTF()

if(swing_lowHTF)
    if(draw_HTF_market_swings == "Low" or draw_HTF_market_swings == "Both")

        while(array.size(HTF_swing_low_label) >= swing_amount)
            label.delete(array.shift(HTF_swing_low_label))
       
        array.push(HTF_swing_low_label, label.new(
                     int(matrix.get(nested_HTF_swing_low, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_swing_low)-1, 0)), 
                     matrix.get(nested_HTF_swing_low, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_swing_low)-1, 3), 
                     yloc = yloc.belowbar, 
                     text = "HTF swing low" + "\n" + str.tostring(matrix.get(nested_HTF_swing_low, matrix.rows(nested_HTF_swing_low)-1, 3)), 
                     color = color.green, 
                     size = size.tiny, 
                     style = label.style_label_up))
```

i have tried using bar replay tool to see if swing points are being displayed while the chart is running through and it picks up the swing points correctly. the issue seems to be on the current bar some disappear. also problem doesnt seem to be the same across different charts.